# Failed to drop/rename a corrupted table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datatable, corruption

In my SQL, a table has corrupted. 
When renaming or removing it, I get this message：

> Possible schema corruption. Run DBCC CHECKCATALOG.  A severe error
>   occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be
>   discarded.

I did tried `DELETE`, `TRUNCATE` and `DROP` but none of these works.

This corrupted table exist in every backup file. The data inside this table is not important, but the main point is to recreate it.
How do I removing this corrupted/damaged table?

Comment: did you run DBCC CHECKDB (<Database Name> WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS

Comment: If you have a full backup, it would probably be simpler to restore the database from zero, and replay the log of the corrupt version if you have it.

Comment: have you actually done it before @GuillaumeF.?

Comment: I'd be thinking about migrating all of the other tables into a new database/file and then burning it.

Comment: @maSTArHiAn Yes I have done it a few years ago. Google is your friend to do it with the newer versions of SQL Server. Before it was a matter of restoring the DB but leave it in restore mode. Then restore the log over.

Answer (score 2):

**Please try the following in order to remove a corruption from a table:**

- To get the exact details about the table corruption, please execute below command:

> ```
> Use YourDatabaseName
> DBCC CHECKTABLE ('YourTableName')
> Go
> ```

- Now since you have the details about the corruption, in order to remove the corruption from a table, you need to DROP and RE-CREATE the PRIMARY KEY of that table as follows:

  > ```
  > Use YourDatabaseName
  > Go
  > ALTER TABLE [YourTableName] DROP CONSTRAINT [Primary Key Constraint Name] 
  > GO
  > ALTER TABLE [YourTableName] ADD CONSTRAINT [Primary Key Constraint Name] Primary Key Clustered (Column(s))
  > GO
  > ```
- Now you can run the DBCC CHECKTABLE command again to confirm that the table corruption has been removed.

**It indeed worked for me.**

All the Best...!!!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/checkdb-from-every-angle-emergency-mode-repair-the-very-very-last-resort/

> Hack the system tables to get the database into EMERGENCY mode. Use
>   the undocumented and unsupported DBCC REBUILD_LOG command to build a
>   new transaction log. Run DBCC CHECKDB with the REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS
>   option to fix up corruptions in the data files – both those that may
>   have caused the issue, and those caused by rebuilding the transaction
>   log (e.g. because an active transaction altering the database
>   structure was lost). Figure out what data was lost or is
>   transactionally inconsistent (e.g. because a transaction altering
>   multiple tables was lost) as far as your business logic is concerned
>   Take the database out of EMERGENCY mode And then all the other stuff
>   like root-cause analysis and getting a better backup strategy